# FCM data message not coming when app is closed in ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated FCM in my flutter project with `flutter_local_notification`. Everything works as expected in Android. However, ios also works almost except when app is closed from history. When app is cleared from history messages are not triggering. I am using only data message in push notification. Please have a look below:

```
{
   "to": "/topics/global",
   "priority": "high",
   "content_available": true,
   "data": {
      "title": "Demo Title",
      "message": "Demo Message",
      "payload": "basic"
   }
}
```

As you can see there is no `notification` object in the json. This configuration is working fine on Android (foreground & background) and for ios only foreground. However, if i add the `notification` object in this json surprisingly `it works even the app is closed`.

But as i need to handle the notification manually that option doesn't fit for my use case. So i researched further and disabled `Method Swizzling`

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key> 
<false/>
```

But that didn't help either. Now i'm kinda lost and can't find a way to achieve expected result. My `AppDelegate.swift` is given below

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
   override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

**NOTE: The ios app is published in TestFlight and testing on a real device**

Comment: Have you registered the background handler?

Comment: Yes i have @Siddharthjha

Comment: In case it helps, I'm from an expo background but they tend to offer nice integration hints in native settings or things that basically boil down to that. Try reading this doc https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/ to see if anything new inspires you.. Look at "Handling incoming notifications when the app is not in the foreground" section specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research i couldn't find an absolute fix for this issue. However, i have implemented a workaround for the issue.

I have 3 scenario of sending notification which are

```
1. Sending notification to specific user
2. Sending notification to all user
3. Sending notification to a topic
```

When user opens the app i check which platform the user is using. If it's Android then i store the device token as android otherwise ios. At the same time i also register the user to a topic `global_android` if platform is `Android` and `global_ios` if platform is `ios`.

Now when i send notification from admin panel i match the condition with above 3 scenario. For android i use following `json` configuration to send notification

```
{
  "to": "topic || token",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "data": {
     "title": "Demo Title",
     "message": "Demo Message",
     "payload": "basic"
  }
}
```

And for `ios` i use following configuration

```
{
  "to": "/topics/global",
  "priority": "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
     "title": "Demo Title",
     "body": "Demo Message"
  },
  "data":{
      "key1":"value",
      "key2":"value"
  }
}
```

And now when i receive the notification i check the platform again. If it's `Android` then i show a custom notification using 'flutter_local_notification' plugin and if it's ios then i do nothing because the notification is shown already by firebase.

**This is not an absolute solve but guess what, it's working for me.**

Comment: The documentation and my own experience suggests iOS does not receive data messages if the app is closed/terminated by swiping it in active apps list. Is your data message working for iOS in this case? For Android it works even if the app is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me. It is error from `firebase_messaging` library. This issue was discussed more than 1 year ago but still no solution. Details see here [FCM Notification IOS](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/6113).